# Can I delete org.blenderfoundation.blender files? / clear space on hard drive

Tags: hardware

I'm very low on ssd space and DaisyDisk says 357,4 GB are occupied with org.blenderfoundation.blender files.
Can I just delete these? These are not actually System files, maybe its something blender creates temporarily? Because some of them are from 3 years back.
Because what could go wrong? In worst case just reinstall Blender.
Any. help would be appreciated as I have no other option where to free up more ssd space.
Thanks!

[image]

[image]